# Ordering by number of associations in common (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**BACKGROUND:** I have Posts and Users, and both have many Communities.

**OBJECTIVE:** For any given User I'd like to return a collection of Posts, ordered by how many communities the post has in common with the user (posts with more communities in-common being higher up)

My current attempt (using the sort method) works:

```
Post.includes(:community_posts).where(community_posts: { community_id: current_user.community_ids }).sort{ |x,y| (y.community_ids & current_user.community_ids).length <=> (x.community_ids & current_user.community_ids).length }
```

but is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding of better/more efficient is that you want to execute the sort in database, rather than Ruby.

Here is a (simpler?) query to return only the posts with communities in common with the user.

```
current_user.posts.joins(:communities).merge(current_user.communities)
```

The `merge` filters the `joins`, one of my favorite new (to me) [ActiveRecord tricks](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/).

Okay, so how can I apply a similar method to ordering by the number of communities in common, instead of just filtering? **Here, this'll do:**

```
current_user.posts.joins(:communities).where(communities: {id: current_user.community_ids}).select('posts.*, COUNT(distinct communities.id) AS community_count').group('posts.id').order('community_count DESC')
```

The `joins` creates a separate Post result for each communities_posts, then we use the `group` and `COUNT` to group those results, in database, by distinct matching communities between the user and post.

Of note, because of the `select`, each record returned will look like a Post but also respond to `post.community_count`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, only one call to the db. Thanks! I was looking to query all posts (not just current_user.posts), so my final query starts with: "Post.joins(:communities)..."

Comment: The one extension of this that I would really like to see is a query that would still include the posts where the number of common communities is zero at the end of the list.

Comment: I've posted an ask requesting an answer to the extension I mentioned in my last comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446662/ordering-by-number-of-associations-in-common-even-if-none-rails